# faraday SSL error when using koala gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, omniauth-facebook, koala-gem

I have this method of code here

```
def facebook 
  @facbeook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end
```

I am logged in to my facebook account I run in the console  `user.facebook.get_object("me")` but i get this error

```
Faraday::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

[Railscast 361](http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api?autoplay=true) shows to pass in the `oauth_token` you obtain from the user login. But doing so I get this error

I am not sure if it is part of my configuration or a general error from something else

**EDIT** I have found here in Koala docs [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/#user-content-talking-to-facebook) about faraday and where you can set SSL certificate. Like this

```
Koala.http_service.http_options = { ssl: { ca_path: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s } }
```

Just need to figure out where to put

Answer (score 0):

Ok fix this by putting in initializer eg koala.rb

```
Koala.http_service.http_options = { ssl: { ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s } }
```

or you can do it on a per request basis like

```
u.facebook.get_object("me", {}, { ssl: { ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s } })
```